# Variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working with React for the last days, so don't blame me. 
But I'm trying to display my full name with a button but I get an error when I d this.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: 'Val',
            surname: 'Vree',
            age: 17,
            nationality: 'Netherlands'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header header={this.state.name} />
                <Content content={this.state.surname} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>I'm {this.props.content}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

How can I put multiple variables in the Content class? Sorry for everything, because I been learning it for some days and I don't have some knowledge of React.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is "multiple variables"?  Do you want to declare a local state with multiple keys and values?  Or do you mean props?  Or do you mean multiple local `private` variables?

Comment: @Kyle I would like to use my this.state.name and this.state.surname in my Content class, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: @user12380607 i've sent the solution

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it in a few ways:

```
 <Content content={ `${this.state.name} ${this.state.surname}`} />
```

or

```
<Content  name={this.state.name} content={this.state.surname} />
```

and get

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>I'm {this.props.name} {this.props.content}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add multiple props. if your feeling lazy want just one prop just pass this.state and you can pass the entire object. but this is bad practice generally.

hope this helps

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: 'Val',
            surname: 'Vree',
            age: 17,
            nationality: 'Netherlands'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* <Header header={this.state.name} /> */}
                <Content 
                  name={this.state.name}              //<----  add more props
                  surname={this.state.surname}
                  age={this.state.age}
                  nationality={this.state.nationality}
                  />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
    <p>I'm {this.props.name} {this.props.surname}</p>
    <p> I am {this.props.age} and i'm from {this.props.nationality}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say variables I think you mean `props`. You can pass props from a parent component to a child component like so

```
<ChildComponent propOne={this.state.stateOne} propTwo={this.state.stateTwo} />
```

Now `ChildComponent` has access to both of those props passed down from the parent component.

In `ChildComponent` you can access `propOne` by doing `props.propOne` (or `this.props.propOne` if `ChildComponent` is a class component).

In your case, you should do

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: 'Val',
            surname: 'Vree',
            age: 17,
            nationality: 'Netherlands'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header header={this.state.name} />
                <Content name={this.state.name} surname={this.state.surname} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>I'm {this.props.name} {this.props.surname}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you! I thought I could do header={[this.state.name,this.state.surname]}, but that was not the case. Now I know I can use more than one prop

Comment: If you're curious you can do something like `header={{name: this.state.name, surname: this.state.surname}}` and then in your child component do `this.props.header.name` and `this.props.header.surname` but keeping props separated is advisable for clarity.

Comment: Of doing what? Keeping them separate? It's just easier for organization and later use. If you stored all of you're values in one prop object it could get really confusing depending on how many props your passing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would try it! Any tips furthermore?

Comment: For this case I don't think so. Just know that the variables you were referring to are considered props when working in react. You can pass multiple props down to other components by adding them inline `<Child propOne={this.state.stateOne} propTwo={this.state.stateTwo} />`. And if my answer works/was helpful feel free to accept it as the answer :)